# routing a secondary IP-addr. of a different private network on the same interface

Tags: linux, networking, ip, routing, network-interface

Typical home-networking **xDSL** setup on a **TG782** router/gateway. Hosts on the local private network are allocated **IP**-addresses in the range of **192.168.1.0/24** and can get to **WAN** through the aforementioned combo device at **192.168.1.254** (the gw for LAN). I'm running **Debian** on one of the machines (**192.168.1.63**) and want to add an **IP-addr.** to the *same interface*, but from a **different** network (i.e. **172.16.1.0/24**) and be able to route packets to the outside network just like I'm doing now with the current setup.

Here are the details of **ifconfig**:

> wlan2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 94:0c:6d:8d:28:0f
>             inet addr:192.168.1.63  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

Output of **route -n**:

> Kernel IP routing table
>   Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
>   0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan2
>   192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan2

So, let's say I will do this:

**ip addr add 172.16.1.62/24 dev wlan2**

What changes would I need to make locally, on this machine, so that I would get this working:

**telnet -b 172.16.1.62 google.com 80**

?

My assumption is that I would probably need to do some form of internal **NAT** with **iptables**, in order to have this properly routed or.. ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan2 -j SNAT -s 172.16.1.62/24
>   --to-source 192.168.1.63

Seems to do just that:

```
# telnet -b 172.16.1.62 google.com 80
Trying 173.194.32.33...
Connected to arn06s02-in-f1.1e100.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
```